# Returning the middle n (values not index) from a collection

Tags: c#, linq, algorithm

I have a `List<int>` and I need to remove the outliers so want to use an approach where I only take the middle n.  I want the middle in terms of values, not index.

For instance, given the following list if I wanted the middle 80% i would expect that the 11 and 100 would be removed.

11,22,22,33,44,44,55,55,55,100.

Is there an easy / built in way to do this in LINQ?

Comment: What should happen when you want the middle 80% of the set 1,2,3?  Will the result be 2?

Comment: This does not strike me as anything even close to a statistically valid approach to removing outliers. What is your *a priori* statistical model? Is it normally distributed? If so, then how does this technique take into account the three sigma rule? This whole thing strikes me as completely dodgy. Why is "11" an outlier here? If you graphed this data it would not appear to lie outside of any particular model that comes to mind. Can you give us more details about what you're trying to do here, and why? This just seems really bizarre.

Comment: @Eric: It's certainly not bizarre. For example, it might be a preparatory step in calculating a [Truncated mean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_mean). This is a common technique to prevent manipulation of the mean in smaller sets - it's used to calculate LIBOR, for example.

Comment: @Ani: Good point. Maybe "bizarre" is too strong. But it certainly would be helpful to know what the purpose of the code is, and what the expected distribution is. If the goal is to discard the lowest and highest scores in the figure skating finals, I really don't care. If the outliers being removed have to do with a manufacturing process, or human-life-safety impacting decision, or are a part of some financial calculation, then that's more serious. Failure to correctly manage outlier statistics has destroyed companies.

Comment: @Eric Lippert: Do you have an example or a reference for your last statement?

Comment: @Ani: Well, LIBOR is still subject to manipulation: cf. recent news: http://seekingalpha.com/article/260473-libor-manipulation-raises-its-head-again

Comment: @Jason: Sure. The trimming only makes it hard for a single (or a few) bank from manipulating the mean by submitting a ridiculously high / low number. If everyone over/under-reports, pretty much any measure of central tendency will be affected.

Comment: @Jason: Examples abound. The recent massive containment failure at the Fukushima nuclear plants; **magnitude nine earthquakes are not outliers as was previously assumed**. The bailout of Long Term Capital Management due to their failure to understand kurtosis risk.  The destruction of the space shuttle Challenger due to a failure to understand that blow-by damage to vital O rings at low temperatures was not anomalous. It turns out that even smart humans are remarkably bad at comprehending what is an outlier, and people die as a result.

Comment: Wow, glad I sparked such a great conversation.  I'm doing performance measurements on our website.  I'm measuring things like time to first byte, time to page render, time to page load etc.  We want to remove outliers becuase some time our server is warming up and some results take 100 times longer than a 'normal' request.  Becuase we do things in production to minimize the server booting time we want to remove those outliers in the sample.  For the same reason a super fast response is probably just as improbable in production given the load we experience on our servers. What should I do?

Answer (score 11):

> I have a `List<int>` and i need to remove the outliers so want to use an approach where I only take the middle n. I want the middle in terms of values, not index.

Removing outliers correctly depends entirely on the statistical model that accurately describes the distribution of the data -- which you have not supplied for us.

On the assumption that it is a normal (Gaussian) distribution, here's what you want to do.

First compute the *mean*.  That's easy; it's just the sum divided by the number of items.

Second, compute the *standard deviation*. Standard deviation is a measure of how "spread out" the data is around the mean. Compute it by:

- take the difference of each point from the mean
- square the difference
- take the mean of the squares -- this is the variance
- take the square root of the variance -- this is the standard deviation

In a normal distribution 80% of the items are within 1.2 standard deviations of the mean. So, for example, suppose the mean is 50 and the standard deviation is 20. You would expect that 80% of the sample would fall between 50 - 1.2 * 20 and 50 + 1.2 * 20. You can then filter out items from the list that are outside of that range.

Note however that this is *not* removing "outliers".  This is removing elements that are more than 1.2 standard deviations from the mean, in order to get an 80% interval around the mean.  In a normal distribution one expects to see "outliers" on a regular basis.  99.73% of items are within three standard deviations of the mean, which means that if you have a thousand observations, it is perfectly normal to see two or three observations more than three standard deviations outside the mean!  In fact, **anywhere up to, say, five observations more than three standard deviations away from the mean when given a thousand observations probably does not indicate an outlier**.

I think you need to very carefully define what you mean by *outlier* and describe why you are attempting to eliminate them. Things that look like outliers are potentially not outliers at all, they are real data that you should be paying attention to.

Also, note that none of this analysis is correct if the normal distribution is incorrect!  You can get into big, big trouble eliminating what look like outliers when in fact you've actually got the entire statistical model wrong.  If the model is more "tail heavy" than the normal distribution then outliers are common, and **not actually outliers**. Be careful! If your distribution is not normal then you need to tell us what the distribution is before we can recommend how to identify outliers and eliminate them.

Comment: shouldn't there be another step in the stddev calculation: take the mean of the squares, *then* take the square root.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [`Enumerable.OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderby.aspx) method to sort your list, then use [`Enumerable.Skip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx) and the [`Enumerable.Take`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx) functions, e.g.:

```
var result = nums.OrderBy(x => x).Skip(1).Take(8);
```

Where `nums` is your list of integers.

Figuring out what values to use as arguments for `Skip` and `Take` should look something like this, if you just want the "middle `n` values":

```
nums.OrderBy(x => x).Skip((nums.Count - n) / 2).Take(n);
```

However, when the result of `(nums.Count - n) / 2` is not an integer, how do you want the code to behave?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're not doing any weighted average funny business:

```
List<int> ints = new List<int>() { 11,22,22,33,44,44,55,55,55,100 };

int min = ints.Min();
double range = (ints.Max() - min);

var results = ints.Select(o => new { IntegralValue = o, Weight = (o - ints.Min()) / range} );

results.Where(o => o.Weight >= .1 && o.Weight < .9);
```

You can then filter on Weight as needed.  Drop the top/botton **n**% as desired.

In your case:

```
results.Where(o => o.Weight >= .1 && o.Weight < .9)
```

***Edit:*** As an extension method, because I like extension methods:

```
public static class Lulz
{
    public static List<int> MiddlePercentage(this List<int> ints, double Percentage)
    {
        int min = ints.Min();
        double range = (ints.Max() - min);

        var results = ints.Select(o => new { IntegralValue = o, Weight = (o - ints.Min()) / range} );

        double tolerance = (1 - Percentage) / 2;
        return results.Where(o => o.Weight >= tolerance && o.Weight < 1 - tolerance).Select(o => o.IntegralValue).ToList();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
List<int> ints = new List<int>() { 11,22,22,33,44,44,55,55,55,100 };
var results = ints.MiddlePercentage(.8);
```

Answer (score 2):

Normally, if you wanted to exclude statistical outliers from a set of values, you'd compute the arithmetic mean and standard deviation for the set, and then remove values lying further from the mean than you'd like (measure in standard deviations). A normal distribution — your classic bell-shaped curve — exhibits the following properties:

- About 68% of the data will lie within +/- 1 standard deviation from the mean.
- About 95% of the data will lie within +/- 2 standard deviations from the mean.
- About 99.7% of the data will lie within +/- 3 standard deviations of the mean.

You can get Linq extension methods for computation of standard deviation (and other statistical functions) at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/LinqStatistics.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to question the validity of calculating outliers since I had a similar need to do exactly this kind of selection. The answer to the specific question of taking the middle n is:

```
List<int> ints = new List<int>() { 11,22,22,33,44,44,55,55,55,100 };
var result = ints.Skip(1).Take(ints.Count() - 2);
```

This skips the first item, and stops before the last giving you just the middle n items. Here is a link to a .NET Fiddle demonstrating this query.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/p1z7em

Answer (score 0):

> I have a List and I need to remove the outliers so want to use an approach where I only take the middle n. I want the middle in terms of values, not index.

If I understand correctly we want to keep any values that fall into the middle 80% of the 11-100 range, or

```
min + (max - min - (max - min) * 0.8) / 2 < x < max - (max - min - (max - min) * 0.8) / 2
```

Assuming an ordered list, we can SkipWhile the values are lower than the `lowerBound`, and then TakeWhile the numbers are lover than the `upperBound`

```
public void Calculalte()
{
    var numbers = new[] { 11, 22, 22, 33, 44, 44, 55, 55, 55, 100 };

    var percentage = 0.8;

    var result = RemoveOutliers(numbers, percentage);
}

private IEnumerable<int> RemoveOutliers(int[] numbers, double percentage)
{
    int min = numbers.First();
    int max = numbers.Last();
    double range = (max - min);
    double lowerBound = min + (range - range * percentage) / 2;
    double upperBound = max - (range - range * percentage) / 2;
    return numbers.SkipWhile(n => n < lowerBound).TakeWhile(n => n < upperBound);   
}
```